# Swarm Dashboard slow to resume game

Tags: libgdx

Has anyone experienced a very slow resume when closing the dashboard of swarm? There is about a 5 second delay in my application where a black screen is displayed after the dashboard is closed and before the actually game screen is rendered. I had originally thought that maybe my show() method for the current was doing too much and causing the lag, but after looking a bit closer I see that the show() method is actually never even called when switching from the swarm dashboard back to the game, I suppose this is due to the fact that Swarm is not operating in a libgdx context but an android one.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's OpenGl context Loss. your assets need to be reloaded. If you have a lot of assets, you should separate them and load them when needed. That will help your game to feel much faster, especially when starting and when coming back from swarm dashboard.

Comment: Thanks, I do have a lot of assets loaded at one time. Knew it would come back to bite me in the end, best change it now.